# Chatify package in Laravel not opening chats

Tags: php, laravel

So, I am developing a basic portfolio website on Laravel. For this purpose: I am using a custom Authenication Controller which looks like this:

```
public function register(Request $req)
{


    $avatar = $req->file('avatar');
    $newAvatar = uniqid() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $avatar->move(public_path('images'), $newAvatar);

    $cover = $req->file('cover');
    $newCover = uniqid() . '.' . $cover->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $cover->move(public_path('images'), $newCover);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $req->input('name'),
        'email' => $req->input('email'),
        'password' => \Hash::make($req->input('password')),
        'avatar' => $newAvatar,
        'cover' => $newCover,
        'bio' => $req->input('about'),
        'expertise' => $req->input('expertise')
    ]);


    $id = $user->id;

    $edlength = count($req->education_name);
    echo $edlength;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $edlength; $i++) {
        Education::create([
            'userid' => $id,
            'institute' => $req->education_name[$i],
            'startyr' => $req->education_startyear[$i],
            'endyr' => $req->education_endyear[$i],
            'details' => $req->education_degree[$i]
        ]);

    }

    $explength = count($req->experience_pos);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $explength; $i++) {
        Experience::create([
            'userid' => $id,
            'position' => $req->experience_pos[$i],
            'company' => $req->experience_company[$i],
            'startyr' => $req->experience_startyear[$i],
            'endyr' => $req->experience_endyear[$i],
            'details' => $req->experience_details[$i]
        ]);

    }

    $skilllength = count($req->skill_name);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $skilllength; $i++) {
        Skill::create([
            'userid' => $id,
            'name' => $req->skill_name[$i],
            'value' => $req->skill_value[$i]
        ]);

    }

    if (\Auth::attempt($req->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return redirect('dashboard');
    }

    return redirect('register');






}


public function login(Request $req){
    if (\Auth::attempt($req->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return redirect('dashboard');
    }
    else{
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

The login and register work fine as the database gets populated the right way and I can use Auth::id() on the dashbord and it prints it fine.

However, when I go to localhost:8000/chatify, it doesn't load the default avatar.png (See Image 1) and when I do search a user and click on him (See Image 2) to chat with him, it doesn't do anything, it stays on the initial chatify page with no default avatar (See Image 3). I am pretty sure my Pusher credentials are entered correctly as I followed everything closely and it was pretty straight forward to do everything on the documentation for Chatify but I can't figure what's going on over here. Moreover, it does say "Connected" as a quick green message on top when I hit "localhost:8000/chatify".

**Image 1**[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**[image]

**Image 3**[image]

Please help out as soon as possible as I am clearly clueless.

Comment: What have you done already to debug? Did you inspect the images? Correct path? Do they exist? Any errors in your browser's Debug console?

Comment: Can you guide me a bit on how to debug. This is my first time making a full fledge project on Laravel so I am pretty clueless right now. The images do exist where the Chatify package expects them to be.